# Is a watch property in vue a lifecycle hook?

Tags: vue.js, vue-mixin

Is any `watch` property included in vuejs lifecycle hooks?

Here you can see this excerpt from [codepen](https://codepen.io/keviinnch/pen/GadqVJ?editors=0000):

```
const myMixin = {
  methods: {
    increment(){
      console.log('methods from mixins')
      this.myData+=2
    }
  },
  watch:{
    myData(){
      console.log('watcher from mixins')
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins:[myMixin],
  data: function () {
    return {
      myData: 0
    }
  },
  methods:{
    increment(){
      console.log('methods from comp')
      this.myData++
    }
  },
  watch:{
    myData(){
      console.log('watcher from component')
    }
  }
});
```

`myData` watcher from myMixin and the component's is called. However normal method from component is overridden.

In the documentation said:

> Hook functions with the same name are merged into an array so that all of them will be called. Mixin hooks will be called before the component’s own hooks.

But, `watch` is not a hook functions / lifecycle hooks right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging) states,

> When a mixin and the component itself contain overlapping options,
> they will be “merged” using appropriate strategies.
>
> For example, data objects undergo a recursive merge, with the
> component’s data taking priority in cases of conflicts.

It's expected that `watch` option will be merged as well as `data` option, and this is what happens in listed example.

Comment: but why `methods` option doesn't merged as well, instead `methods` in component taking priority. What are other options that will be merged, and what are options that will be taking component's option as priority and overridden the mixin's one?

Comment: That members are overridden is the behaviour that's expected from mixin pattern, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin . As for Vue mixin implementation, it tries to address common cases by additionally merging hooks and some options, notably `data` and `watch`, possibly there's more. `methods` aren't among merged options because this would cause more harm than good. You can access overridden method with `this.$parent.foo()` if you need that.

Comment: Also, if there's anyone that know what options that will be merged and what other options that will be overridden, please comment it, I really appreciate it, Thanks.

Comment: @KevinChandra you can see the full list here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/options.js#L208

Answer (score 1):

The logic for the default merging strategy for all the keys can be found in [vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/options.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/options.js#L208) file in the Vue repo.

As you'll see at line 208, the `watch` key has a special merge strategy which results in creating an array (similar to the logic for the hooks).